# jQuery Drop Down menu - hover and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a menu that shows when you hover over a "Menu" link in the header.  Right now the drop down menu is showing/hiding through CSS.  I would like to keep the hover functionality, but also add a jQuery feature where if you click the word "Menu" it toggles the menu and keeps it open, even if you move your mouse away.

I can do one or the other but haven't figured out if it's possible to combine both.

Here's the javascript that I have for the click/toggle:

```
$("#menu-drop-arrow").click(function(){
    var a=300;
    $("#menu").slideToggle(a);
    $("#hide_menu").click(function(){
        $("#menu").slideUp(a)
    })
});
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to have the menu show and hide by hovering it, but if you click the link it will keep the menu open until you click the link again?

Thank you!

EDIT ***********************************************

Here's a sample of the menu code if it helps any:

```
<div id="menu-drop">
 <div id="menu-drop-arrow"><span id="menu-text">Menu</span>
 <div class="show_col">
 <div class="menucat">
 <ul class="menuitem">
   *** menu links here **
 </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="menucat">
 <ul class="menuitem">
   *** menu links here ***
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need code to remember which mode the menu is in.  Let's call the modes, for instance, "hover" and "stay"

When the menu is clicked, the mode will be toggled.  Also, you'll have to change what your hover event does according to the mode.  (i.e. if the mode is "hover", do normal show/hide; if the mode is "stay", do nothing)

Comment: Care to expand on this with an example or a snippet of code? As it stands, this isn't much of an answer and will provide little help for those who stumble across this post in the future.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  Unfortunately that goes beyond my abilities with javascript

Comment: Dryden, the original question didn't include any HTML markup or even the code for how the hover is being set up in the first place.  I could spin my wheels and write up an entire example from scratch, but we can't ever assume (and this is not a slight in any way) that the OP could analyze my example and actually use any of it.  So the question asked, is it possible.  Yes, it's possible.  But implementation will vary - there's no magic bullet.